# FFMPEG: tee pseudo-muxer to RTMP endpoint with authorization

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I have an RTMP server which requires authorization to stream to. In FFMPEG, I can stream to it like so:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <input> \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -c:a speex \
    -f flv \
    "rtmp://server/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id"
```

Now I wish to split this stream out to ***two*** such endpoints ***without re-encoding***

I can get it working with re-encoding like so:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <input> \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -c:a speex \
    -f flv \
    "rtmp://server1/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id"
    -c:v libx264 \
    -c:a speex \
    -f flv \
    "rtmp://server2/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id"
```

However I tried taking a look at [FFMPEG's guide on this subject](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepseudo-muxer) and it led to nothing but errors:

### Attempt 1

Direct usage of `-f tee`

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <input> \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -c:a speex \
    -f tee \
    -map 0:v \
    -map 0:a \
    "[f=flv]rtmp://server1/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id| \
     [f=flv]rtmp://server2/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id"
```

Yields:

```
[rtmp @ 0x3fe7f40] No credentials set
[rtmp @ 0x3fe7f40] Server error: [ AccessManager.Reject ] : [ code=403 need auth ] :
```

### Attempt 2

Using quotes around URL and parameters

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <input> \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -c:a speex \
    -f tee \
    -map 0:v \
    -map 0:a \
    "[f=flv]\"rtmp://server1/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id\"| \
     [f=flv]\"rtmp://server2/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id\""
```

Yields:

```
[tee @ 0x39837e0] Slave '[f=flv]"rtmp://server1/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id"': error opening: No such file or directory
```

### Attempt 3

Quotes around **everything**

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <input> \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -c:a speex \
    -f tee \
    -map 0:v \
    -map 0:a \
    "\"[f=flv]rtmp://server1/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id\"| \
     \"[f=flv]rtmp://server2/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id\""
```

Yields:

```
[NULL @ 0x393a820] Unable to find a suitable output format for '"[f=flv]rtmp://server1/instance live=true pubUser=user pubPasswd=pass playpath=stream_id"'
```

### Attempt 4

Alternate URL schema to avoid spaces

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <input> \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -c:a speex \
    -f tee \
    -map 0:v \
    -map 0:a \
    "[f=flv]rtmp://user:pass@server1/instance/stream_id| \
     [f=flv]rtmp://user:pass@server2/instance/stream_id"
```

This **seemed** to work, but FFMPEG started outputting this:

```
frame=   89 fps= 13 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:03.27 bitrate=N/A dup=18 drop=0 speed=0.469x
```

Notice the `bitrate=N/A` and the `speed=0.469x`? Both concerns. Then I go to the player to watch my stream and it's solid black. No data is actually coming through.

**What am I doing wrong, and how do I get this stream working?**

Comment: Have you tried with escaped single quotes around the URLs? Or try without quotes but escape whitespace.

Comment: Both single quotes and escaped spaces give the `[ code=403 need auth ]` error

Comment: The quotes were still around the tee arguments, right? And did you double-escape the spaces?

Comment: I tried various combinations of single-quotes, escaped single-quotes, escaped double-quotes, spaces, escaped spaces, double-escaped spaces, and even triple-escaped spaces. No dice. I did, however, find a workaround to my problem for now. Instead of using `-f tee`, I can output to stdout and have a second instance of ffmpeg stream using `-c copy`